# CSS treating 'root' differently in external .css file

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to CSS and have found a nuance that I don't understand.
I'm trying to set the viewport background color, and using the color red in this example.

If I use the following code in an external .css file then add it to my html file in the 'head' section, the viewport color is NOT changing at all -- it is the standard white background:

```
 ==== my-external-css-file.css ===
 root 
{ 
   display: block;
   background-color:RGB(255,0,0);     
}


==== my index.html file ====
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>theRed</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-external-css-file.css"
</head>
```

I am learning CSS using a book and the book uses the external .CSS file approach that does not work.  So I took upon myself to abandon the external CSS file and put the root's color change *directly* in the "head" section of my index.html file -- if I instead put the root color I want **directly inside** index.html, the entire viewport background is red as expected:

```
     ==== my index.html file ====
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>theRed</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>

    <style type="text/css"> 
        :root
        {
            background-color:RGB(255,0,0);
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Since both times I'm setting the root's "background-color" to red, and in both cases I'm doing so in the correct part of the html file, in the "head" section -- why is the external .css file's attempt to set the background color NOT working?

I'm new to CSS so I'm thinking there is some nuance here I'm not aware of?   I'm using Netbeans for my development IDE and when I create a new .CSS file, Netbeans is automatically putting the "display: block" statement in the new .css file so I assumed it was needed and left that alone.

Comment: In one you're using `root` and in the other `:root`. Looks like my css knownledge is a bit outdates, since I've never heard of either. I'd guess `:root` is some kind of pseudo-selector, and `root` would require a html tag called `root`. Does replacing `root` with `:root` in the first example fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `root` node of HTML is the `<html>` element, so the selector should be `html` **not** `root`.

In your external CSS, you have forgotten the `:` for the [`:root` pseudo-selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3aroot). In HTML it will always be `html` so there is no reason to use `:root` AFAIK.

Comment: Using :root inside index.html turned the entire viewport background red.  My external style sheet above did not have the :root, only root (no colon), and did not work.  The nuance I've learned, perhaps, is that :root defaults to the html tag, but the word root by itself does not.  Because when I changed the :root above inside index.html to root (no colon) -- the red background stopped working.  When I changed the external .css file's root to :root the red background appeared.  Thanks, I was hoping it was something basic and not some weird difference between in-file css and external-file css.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `root` you can either use elements like `html` or `body` for color.
I think in your example you would set your body to:

```
body {
    background-color:RGB(255,0,0);
}
```